# asciiSetupReader trouble with .sps files with RECORDS feature or .sas files with n= feature

Tags: r, sas, spss

I'm trying to use R and asciiSetupReader to load data from the ECLS-K dataset from https://nces.ed.gov/ecls/dataproducts.asp

The ECLSK_Kto8_child_SPSS.sps file there includes the following; note the use of "RECORDS = 15":

```
DATA LIST FILE=FHAND FIXED RECORDS = 15 TABLE
/1
   CHILDID 1-8 (A)
```

etc. Then around line 1630 of the file it says:

```
   P1AGE_17 5300-5302
/2
   P1SEX_17 1-2
```

etc. So, the column numbers have dropped from about 5300 back to 1, for the start of the second "record". Something like this happens for /3, /4, ... , /15. I found this SPSS web page that describes that feature: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spss-statistics/24.0.0?topic=list-records-subcommand-data-command

I am guessing that this is what causes an error from asciiSetupReader that says

```
The following columns have a start number greater than the end number. Please check your setup file and fix this issue before rerunning this code.
Columns with issue:  NA
```

though that happens only 6 times, not 15 times for the 15 records.

I tried to use the ECLSK_Kto8_child_SAS.sas file also posted at that website, and it also didn't work; it contains this:

```
 infile in1 lrecl=5310 n=15;
      input 
   #1
      @1 CHILDID $8.
```

so I'm guessing that the n=15 and #1 indicates the same issue as with the .sps file.

I tried using `make_sps_setup` to make a little setup file that includes just the variables that I want:

```
data list
C5R4MTSC      2002-2007
C6R4MTSC      2256-2261
T5ARSMAT      2862-2866
T6ARSMAT      2912-2916
M7COURSE      1550-1551
.

variable labels
C5R4MTSC      "C5 RC4 MATH T-SCORE"
C6R4MTSC      "C6 RC4 MATH T-SCORE"
T5ARSMAT      "T5 MATH ARS SCORE"
T6ARSMAT      "T6 MATH ARS SCORE"
M7COURSE      "M7 Q14 DESCRIBE THIS MATH COURSE"
.
```

However, `M7COURSE      1550-1551` happens in record 5, while the others are in record 1, so I have no confidence that I will be getting the right values. And, I would lose the codebook information about what the numeric values mean, though I could probably figure out how to take care of that.

I suppose I could try making a version  of the .sps and .dat files that only have stuff from record 1, then make another copy of them that have only stuff from record 5, but I don't know how records are delineated in the .dat file. And that idea seems awfully prone to error.

Any ideas on how I can read this data with R? Thanks!

Comment: If you can supply a better link to the data I could take a look

Comment: The .sps file is at https://nces.ed.gov/ecls/data/ECLSK_Kto8_child_SPSS.sps and the .sas file is at https://nces.ed.gov/ecls/data/ECLSK_Kto8_child_SAS.sas ; both of those are not huge (2-4 MB). The data itself is huge (1+ GB unzipped) and is at https://nces.ed.gov/ecls/data/Childk8p.zip

Comment: Are you asking for help enhancing that R package to understand how to handle parsing the code for reading multiple line data?  Do you know what R code the package should be generating to read a text file where the data takes multiple lines?

Comment: Generally, the idea of `RECORDS = 15` is that every case, or row, in the final data is folded into 15 rows in the raw data file. So the structure of the definition file is good, and it works in spss - I checked (tho won't try to get the data itself :) ) - so this isn't where your problem is.

Comment: I know it would be too much to ask for help enhancing the R package. I am hoping someone says something like "this other R package can handle that situation" or "here is a little script I found that can transform the data into a format without the RECORDS= issue, then asciiSetupReader can read it".